# Toy Neural Network or fancy squiggly line generator?

Tags: python, neural-network, turtle-graphics

I have written this code to better understand machine learning but I am unsure if I am on the right track or not. So far it draws random squiggly lines all over the screen using python 3.7.

```
import turtle
import random

# Sets the Turtle main screen color 
turtle.bgcolor("pink")

# Settings for bug sprite
bug = turtle.Turtle()
bug.penup()
bug.color("red")
bug_x = bug.setx(-150)
bug_y = bug.sety(12)
bug.pendown()

# Settings for food sprite
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.penup()
food.color("green")
food_x = food.setx(160)
food_y = food.sety(59)
food.pendown()



# Main Loop
while True:


    # X and Y coordinate of Food
    destination = [160,59]

    # X and Y coordinate of Bug
    x_1 = bug.xcor()
    y_1 = bug.ycor()
    origin = [x_1,y_1]

    learn = .10
    bias = 0

    # Weights
    wghts = [random.uniform(-1,1),random.uniform(-1,1),random.uniform(-1,1),
             random.uniform(-1,1),random.uniform(-1,1),random.uniform(-1,1)]
    #print(wghts)




    # Output Neurons
    output_1 = (wghts[0] * origin[0]) + (wghts[1] * origin[1]) + bias
    output_2 = (wghts[2] * origin[0]) + (wghts[3] * origin[1]) + bias
    output_3 = (wghts[4] * origin[0]) + (wghts[5] * origin[1]) + bias

    #Relu Function
    if output_1 >= 0.1:
        output_1 = output_1
    else:
        output_1 = 0

    if output_2 >= 0.1:
        output_2 = output_2
    else:
        output_2 = 0

    if output_3 >= 0.1:
        output_3 = output_3
    else:
        output_3 = 0

    # Compares food/destination X and Y with bug/origin X and Y.
    # applies update ("learn") to all weights
    if origin[0] != destination[0] and origin[1] != destination[1]:
        wghts[0] = wghts[0] + learn
        wghts[1] = wghts[1] + learn
        wghts[2] = wghts[2] + learn
        wghts[3] = wghts[3] + learn
        wghts[4] = wghts[4] + learn
        wghts[5] = wghts[5] + learn
    else:
        wghts[0] = wghts[0] 
        wghts[1] = wghts[1] 
        wghts[2] = wghts[2] 
        wghts[3] = wghts[3] 
        wghts[4] = wghts[4] 
        wghts[5] = wghts[5]

    #print(wghts)
    #print("\n")

    # Creates a barrier for turtle
    bug_1a = int(bug.xcor())
    bug_2a = int(bug.ycor())

    if bug_1a > 300 or bug_2a > 300:
        bug.penup()
        bug.setx(5)
        bug.sety(5)
        bug.pendown()
    if bug_1a < -300 or bug_2a < -300:
        bug.penup()
        bug.setx(5)
        bug.sety(5)
        bug.pendown()

    # Output values applied to turtle direction controls
    bug.forward(output_1)
    bug.right(output_2)
    bug.left(output_3)
```

Comment: What do you mean *"on the right track"*? To *where?*

Comment: Hi  jonrsharpe!  I am uncertain if I am understanding Neural Networks correctly. I wrote this code as an exercise in what I have learned so far, however, I'm in need of some expert eyes.

Comment: Hi, can you please be more specific in your question? Would be helpful to explain what your code currently does, why it does it and what you ultimately want it to do.

Comment: The goal is for the turtle/bug to find and learn the (currently static)food source represented by a green turtle. it uses X and Y (as planes) to represent its current position. these variables are the inputs which feed directly to three output nodes that will move the turtle forward, right and left. the update function uses an if statement that compares the coordinate values of both the food source and turtle/bug. if they are not the same, the learn variable is added to all weights

Answer (score 0):

Issues I see with your program:

The `wghts` learn nothing from the previous iteration -- they are randomly reset each time through the loop.

The `output_1`, `output_2` and `output_3` are calculated from the freshly reinitialized `wghts` so the changes made by:

```
if origin[0] != destination[0] and origin[1] != destination[1]:
        wghts[0] = wghts[0] + learn
        ...
        wghts[5] = wghts[5] + learn
```

are never reflected in the `output_*` variables.

You're adding the bug's X and Y coordinates and using that as the number of degrees to turn.  Twice.  I don't see how that makes any sense, but I guess it's a neural network thing.

You do your barrier check too late in the code such that it's out of sync with what follows.  The bug isn't moving, so do the check earlier.

The following code cleanup won't make your bug any less random -- just hopefully make your code easier to work with:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import uniform

# Sets the Turtle main screen color
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("pink")

# X and Y coordinate of Food
destination = (160, 59)

# Settings for food sprite
food = Turtle()
food.color("green")
food.penup()
food.setposition(destination)
food.pendown()

start = (-150, 12)

# Settings for bug sprite
bug = Turtle()
bug.color("red")
bug.penup()
bug.setposition(start)
bug.pendown()

LEARN = 0.1
BIAS = 0

# Main Loop
while True:

    # X and Y coordinate of Bug
    x, y = bug.position()

    # Creates a barrier for turtle
    if not -300 <= x <= 300 or not -300 <= y <= 300:
        bug.penup()
        bug.goto(start)
        bug.pendown()
        origin = start
    else:
        origin = (x, y)

    # Weights
    wghts = [uniform(-1, 1), uniform(-1, 1), uniform(-1, 1), uniform(-1, 1), uniform(-1, 1), uniform(-1, 1)]

    # Compares food/destination X and Y with bug/origin X and Y.
    # applies update ("LEARN") to all weights
    if origin != destination:
        wghts[0] += LEARN
        wghts[1] += LEARN
        wghts[2] += LEARN
        wghts[3] += LEARN
        wghts[4] += LEARN
        wghts[5] += LEARN

    # Output Neurons
    output_1 = (wghts[0] * origin[0]) + (wghts[1] * origin[1]) + BIAS
    output_2 = (wghts[2] * origin[0]) + (wghts[3] * origin[1]) + BIAS
    output_3 = (wghts[4] * origin[0]) + (wghts[5] * origin[1]) + BIAS

    # Relu Function
    if output_1 < 0.1:
        output_1 = 0

    if output_2 < 0.1:
        output_2 = 0

    if output_3 < 0.1:
        output_3 = 0

    # Output values applied to turtle direction controls
    bug.forward(output_1)
    bug.right(output_2)
    bug.left(output_3)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great questions! and thank you cdlane for the code cleanup.